# Using phonegap on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have created a simple app using phonegap which runs correctly on my android device, I used phonegap cloud to cross compile the source, but it can't compile to iOS.

I read the documentation here:
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds

Does this imply that I can only run the app on one specific test device? Or is it the same concept as with the android and I can download the iOS .apk equivalent onto any device I choose and run it? Or with iOS is it only possible to deploy to many devices via the iOS market? If this is the case how can I compile the phonegap source to be deployable to iOS?

Essentially, my question is - how can I deploy my phonegap code to any iOS device I choose? Do I need to do this through apple?

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap is a wonderful tool, and it definitely simplifies the process of creating apps, but Apple still exert much greater control over what gets on their devices, so once you have your app you still need the following to deploy it.

A minimum of

- Paid Membership of the Developer program €99
- I don't think you actually require a Mac as you should be able to simply upload the binary through the browser.
- Time - you will need some to figure our how to set up certificates etc to get it all working.

Answer (score 1):

You need a mac and register to the apple dev program.

Comment: Once I have that though, I can upload the binary that phonegap generates?

Comment: You don't need a MAC to upload a binary. You need a mac to generate the binary from XCode. -1